# How can I find initial and final velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, velocity

Is there a way to find initial and final velocity if I only know the acceleration and distance and which formula must I use? I do not know the time either.

**EDIT**
Thank you for all your answers! You were right I didn't know enough to solve the problem. How ever it was just the first part of a two parts task. And at first I thought that the second part is even less doable since it had more unknown variables. It appears that I was wrong and I should have started from there instead.
[image] 
This is the exercise and I solved it using a system with four equations and four unknown variables to solve it. The variables in question being V<sub>c</sub>, V<sub>b</sub>, t and γ. Once I found V<sub>B</sub> it was easy to do the rest.
I suck at thinking like a mathematician.

By the way this is my first question and I am not yet familiar with the etiquette of this site. Am I supposed to  delete  a question once it has come to a conclusion or leave it so others can see?

Comment: what is the initial condition at time t=0?

Comment: Hey, this question is probably more interesting if we see that in its literal meaning! The OP thinks probably on linear movement with constant acceleration on the Newtonian mechanics (to copy-paste the answer into his homework, and then forget the whole thing _forever_), but he doesn't mention them. What is the case in general? :-)

Comment: First, yes this is my homework but I am not asking you to solve it I am asking how can I solve it. Second I am not a native English speaker so excuse me for that but I will try to explain where I am coming from.
I have a object moving upwards on a slope its angle is 70 degrees  but I do not think that is important. I had all the forces applied to the object and the mass of it as well. So using that I calculated that the acceleration is equal to - 7.095 m/s^2. Unfortunately that is all I know and also that the distance or the length of the slope is equal to 1.1m. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is the acceleration constant?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

(Source of image: Mohsin Khan, http://cslearners.blogspot.com/2009/08/equation-of-motion.html)

Here they are! All the formulas.

Sorry to say, you cannot find anything if you have only acceleration and distance. Think like this, Say you have an object that has an acceleration of 2 m/s^2. and if i say that if travels a distance of 2 meters. It can travel those two meters in any time period, may be 1 s or 0.23s. I HAVE TO METION time, to make sense of the statement.

Things are very different, if they say that the object started form rest.

Comment: Could you please give the source of your equations - it looks like a picture from somewhere, and we expect attribution where possible.

Comment: @Floris, i took it form google images

Comment: Google images is not a source. It's like answering the question "Who wrote that book?" with "I got it from the library".

Comment: @Floris Hahaha. Nice sense of humour :p 
This is the link to the site. https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjOkKfD3OPMAhXLO48KHZ_eDWIQjB0IBg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcslearners.blogspot.com%2F2009%2F08%2Fequation-of-motion.html&psig=AFQjCNFL6OQw76CdARIRWJWvwgNBOgVOfA&ust=1463664289353097

Answer (score 3):

If you draw a velocity-time graph you will see that you do not have enough information to find the initial and final velocity.

[image]

The gradient of the graph is fixed because it is the acceleration.
The distance is the area under the velocity-time graph.
As you will see from the graph you can draw an infinite number of trapeziums (or triangles) which satisfy the known acceleration and known distance condition.

The graph also shows you which additional parameter you need to define to uniquely position a trapezium.

Comment: Very nicely answered! The graph really does make it intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Under constant acceleration, the relationships between velocity, acceleration, distance and time are:

$$\begin{align}v_t &= v_0 + a_t\\
x_t &= x_0 + v_0 t + \frac12 a t^2\end{align}$$

When a and d ($x_t$) are given, you are left with two equations and three unknowns: $v_0$, $v_t$ and $t$.

This means you cannot come up with a numerical (unique) solution, unless you have more information. Perhaps if you read the question carefully, you discover that after 1.1 m the object is stationary (is it the highest point it reaches?).

We can't guess what other information you have; but I can tell you that mathematically speaking, two equations with three unknowns do not have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming constant acceleration**

You have to know the time also. If you know the distance traveled $s$ after time $t$ then you can write

$$ s = v_0 t + \frac{1}{2} a t^2 $$ and solve for the initial velocity $$v_0 = \frac{s}{t} - \frac{a t}{2} $$

Once the initial velocity is known, then the final velocity is

$$ v_1 = v_0 + a t $$

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. Unless the body is starting or ending at rest in which case $v_f$ or $v_i$ would be zero and you could substitute in $0$ in the eq: $v_f^2 = v_i^2+2aS$

Intuitively this makes sense. If the acceleration and distance for which the body accelerates are known, you can only determine $v_f^2- v_i^2$
You don't know whether $V_i = 0m/s$ and $V_f =10 m/s$ which gives $v_f^2- v_i^2 = 100$ or if $V_i = 9m/s $ and$ V_f \approx 13.45 m/s$ **which also gives** $v_f^2- v_i^2 \approx 100$ or the countless other solutions. However, if you have $V_f$ or $V_i$ in this case, you can find the other.